# How to make error log more detailed about undefined reference to

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, cygwin

I need to compile some c/c++ code.  Using the tools of NDK and Cygwin, more than one time I have come up with the error "undefined reference to".  Most guys said that it is caused by invoking a function whose lib file isn't included in your source file.  However, I know little about c/c++, and also the error log gives fuzzy info so I can not know in which file which line cause the problem, not even know which lib file it is that I really need.

My hope is that I find some tools or some ways to deal with problems like this so I can locate the error line or get some more detail about the error.

Thanks a lot.

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include ../includeOpenCV.mk
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OPENCV_MK_PATH))","")
#try to load OpenCV.mk from default install location
include $(TOOLCHAIN_PREBUILT_ROOT)/user/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
else
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
endif
LOCAL_MODULE:=AvatarSpeak
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=AvatarSpeak.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**$NDK/ndk-build V=1**

```
$ $NDK/ndk-build V=1
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so        ./libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver     ./libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup      ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
mkdir -p ./libs/armeabi
install -p /cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8b/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver   ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
mkdir -p ./libs/armeabi
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi" > ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
echo "directory D:/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include   "../../OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/../../include/opencv" "../../OpenCV-    2.3.1/share/OpenCV/../../include" D:/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-     libstdc++/4.6/include D:/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-    libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/include jni" >> ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
SharedLibrary  : libAvatarSpeak.so
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-     4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -Wl,-soname,libAvatarSpeak.so  -shared       --sysroot=D:/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm  ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-      debug/AvatarSpeak/com_huawei_avatar_AvatarSpeak.o ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_contrib.a       ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_calib3d.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_objdetect.a       ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_features2d.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_video.a      ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_imgproc.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_highgui.a          ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_ml.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_legacy.a     ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_flann.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_core.a        ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_androidcamera.a ./obj/local/armeabi/liblibjpeg.a       ./obj/local/armeabi/liblibpng.a ./obj/local/armeabi/liblibtiff.a      ./obj/local/armeabi/liblibjasper.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libzlib.a       ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a    -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-      z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -LD:/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib -llog -lc -           lm  -o obj/local/armeabi/libAvatarSpeak.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/AvatarSpeak/AvatarSpeak.o: In function      `Java_com_hachi_avatar_AvatarSpeak_speak':
D:\eclipse_workspace\TestSo/jni/com_hachi_avatar_AvatarSpeak.cpp:52: undefined     reference to `Fap2Avi2D(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*,    int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target     `obj/local/armeabi/libAvatarSpeak.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libAvatarSpeak.so] Error 1
```

**AvatarSpeak.cpp**

```
if (fImage != NULL && fPot != NULL) {

    bool sucavi = Fap2Avi2D(str3, str5, str4, str1, str2, -1);
    LOGI("sucess and exit!");
} else {
    LOGI("unsucess and exit!");
}
```

**Animation2D_new.h**(the head file where define the method **Fap2Avi2D**)

```
#ifndef ANIMATION_2D_NEW_H_
#define ANIMATION_2D_NEW_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "public.h"
#include "FaceExpressionEditor.h"
//#define  __declspec(dllexport)

bool Fap2Avi2D(const char *fap_file,const char *avi_file,const char *wav_file, const   char* image_file,const char *pot_file=NULL,int codec_type=-1);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, "undefined reference" means that your build is misconfigured. For example, an unintended line break in the `Android.mk` file could cause the **make** tool choose a wrong link command for your project.

Usually the error message includes the name of the missing function or global variable, and the module (file) which was looking for this reference. If the name is not self-explanatory, you can often find this name called in your source code, and then track it back to one of the external libraries you use, because it is likely to be **declared** in some header (**.h** or **.hpp**) files included in your source.

It is not likely that you unintentionally use some external library which you have to download, because usually such mistakes manifest themselves earlier, when the compiler cannot find the necessary include (header) files.

One particular case for Android native projects to display "undefined reference" errors is when the project uses non-official Android APIs, e.g. OpenMax/stagefreight. In such cases, the header files are found in the Android source tree, but compiled libraries needed for the link phase are not there. The usual workaround is to pull the binaries from your development device, e.g.

```
adb pull /system/lib/libstagefreight.so .
```

Anyways, it often helps to run `ndk-build` with **V=1** to see exactly what build commands are executed.

Comment: hi,Alex, after reading your post, still i cannot find clue to deal with my problem, so I post some of my codes, hope you can give me some more detailed solutions. Lots of thanks.

Comment: Well, file `Animation2D_new.h` is used to **declare** the `Fap2Avi2D()` function, but does not [**define**](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html) it. You probably have the corresponding `Animation2D_new.cpp` file somewhere; you should explicitly add it to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to find "the missing library". This is where your skill as a programmer (and Google user) has to be activated.

The first step is always to identify which library the function belongs to. Using Google is always a good bet.

When your know this, you need to find out if that library is installed on your system. If not, make it so.

Then you need to add this dependency to your build system. How this is done depends on the environment and tools used. Google is yet again your best bet.